# exec での外部コマンドの実行結果を表示すると文字化けが発生する

Tags: php, 文字化け

phpでpingを使った疎通確認ができるWebページを作成したんですが、画像のように結果が文字化けします。
XAMPPを使用しており、php.iniは「default_charset = UTF-8」、「mbstring.language = Japanese」、「mbstring.internal_encoding = UTF-8」に設定しなおしましたが治りません。一応、コードも載せておきます。原因と対処法分かる方いたら教えてください。

[image: 文字化け]

[image: OSのシステム情報]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="ja">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ping Check</title>
</head>

<body style="text-align:center;">
    <h1>Ping Check</h1>
    <?php
    print "IP address<br>\n";
    ?>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" size="30" name="ipaddress" placeholder="8.8.8.8"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="check">
    </form>

    <?php

    if (!empty($_POST["ipaddress"])) {
        $ipaddress = $_POST["ipaddress"];
        echo exec("ping -n 1 " . $ipaddress);
    }
    ?>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`exec()`のドキュメント](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.exec.php#refsect1-function.exec-notes)には

> **警告** ユーザーが入力したデータをこの関数に 渡すことを許可する場合、ユーザーが任意のコマンドを実行できるようシステムを欺くことが できないように escapeshellarg() または escapeshellcmd() を適用する必要があります。

とあります。気を付けるべきです。

---

具体的には

> ```
> <form method="post">
>   <input type="text" size="30" name="ipaddress" placeholder="8.8.8.8"><br>
>   <input type="submit" value="check">
> </form>
> <?php
> if (!empty($_POST["ipaddress"])) {
>   $ipaddress = $_POST["ipaddress"];
>   echo exec("ping -n 1 " . $ipaddress);
> }
> ?>
> ```

とのことなので、IP address として

```
127.0.0.1 && shutdown /s /t 0
```

と入力したら、シャットダウンコマンドが実行されて、PCが停止しませんか？

Answer (score 0):

文字コードを変換してあげると解決すると思います。
また、execコマンドが最後の1行しか取得できていなかったので、こちらも直してみました。
これに伴って、少しエラー対策も入れています。
参考になれば幸いです。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="ja">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ping Check</title>
</head>

<body style="text-align:center;">
    <h1>Ping Check</h1>
    <?php
    print "IP address<br>\n";
    ?>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" size="30" name="ipaddress" placeholder="8.8.8.8"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="check">
    </form>

    <?php

    if (!empty($_POST["ipaddress"])) {
        $ipaddress = $_POST["ipaddress"];
        $output = null;
        $exitcode = null;
        exec("ping -n 1 " . $ipaddress, $output, $exitcode);
        $output = nl2br(mb_convert_encoding(implode("\n", $output), "utf-8", "auto"));
        if ($exitcode == 0){
            echo $output;
        }else{
            echo "PINGの実行に失敗しました。<br>";
            echo $output;
        }
    }
    ?>

</body>

</html>
```

参考：
[文字コードの変換：mb_convert_encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)
[配列の連結：implode](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.implode.php)
[改行を `<br>` タグに変換する：nl2br](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.nl2br.php)